# Get file path on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a problem trying to get the **file path** on chrome. This is my code with a **javascript** function:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getPath() {
 var inputName = document.getElementById('ctrl');
 var imgPath;

 imgPath = inputName.value;
 //alert(imgPath);
 var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", imgPath);
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="file" name ="file1" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="getPath()"/>

</body>
</html>
```

when I press the button, the textfield show me this

```
C:\fakepath\ART.pdf
```

I tried to edit the internet explorer settings and it works fine, but I cant get the full path on chrome
Its any way to get the full path on **chrome**? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the path?

Comment: To allow the user to select the directory where some files are going to be saved

Comment: You can't access it for obvious security reasons. Do you want any website to be able to see your directory structure?

Comment: Basically chrome, because my project with icefaces doesnt work well in ie.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the multiple and directory options so your paths will be avaible under inputName.files

For security reasons these will be relative paths. If you wish to read the files you need to use the FileReader API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

I read in the comments that you are trying to save a file to a specific location. This can't be achieved through a browser. You just need to provide the file to be downloaded and the user will decide where to save it. Usually, it will be saved to the OS's default download folder.

Comment: But the fileReader API doesnt helps me to get the complete path. It also shows me with fakepath